# How to resolve $TERM not set on gradlew ./assembleRelease on CIrcleCI?

Tags: gradle, android-build, circleci-2.0

I'm building a workflow on circleci 2.0 and so far jobs are running until it gets to android job.

At the build step `./gradlew assembleRelease` it fails stating that an ENV VAR is not set:

```
Unzipping /home/circleci/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip to /home/circleci/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv
Set executable permissions for: /home/circleci/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.14.1-all/8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv/gradle-2.14.1/bin/gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open terminal for stdout: $TERM not set
```

What I did try according to [this post](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015516048-Gradle-TERM-not-set) is setting the $TERM variable is a run command prior to the gradle invocation. But the build still fails looking for this variable.

Question:

How can you resolve $TERM not set on gradlew ./assembleRelease on CIrcleCI?

I did verify that I'm using the correct docker image according to this SO post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45744987/1829251

Here is the config.yml gist of the `android` CI Job:

```
 android:
    working_directory: ~/repo/android
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-25-node8-alpha
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/repo
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/repo
      - run: ./gradlew androidDepedencies    
      - run: export TERM=xterm   
      - run: sudo chmod +x ./gradlew
      - run: ./gradlew assembleRelease
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - store_test_results:
path: ~/repo/android/reports
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*disclaimer: Developer Evangelist at CircleCI*

```
      - run: export TERM=xterm
```

That line sets the variable `$TERM` only for that specific shell. Each `run` step starts a brand new shell.

Your solution of running `gradlew` in the same step is one possible solution:

```
 - run: export TERM=xterm && ./gradlew androidDepedencies
```

Another would be to properly export `$TERM` so that all subsequent steps can see the variable. This would be done like this:

```
      - run: echo 'export TERM=xterm' >> $BASH_ENV
```

`$BASH_ENV` contains the path to the Bash file that is sourced at the beginning of every CircleCI `step`. Here's where this came from: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#setting-path

Comment: thanks that is a good tip on making the var global in config!

Comment: Why doesn't the CircleCI example code include this if gradle requires it?

Comment: I was going to add it but it looks like `$TERM` is now already set in those images.

Answer (score 0):

I was exporting the ENV VAR incorrectly, using the following fixed the missing `$TERM not set` erorr in the android build:

```
 - run: export TERM=xterm && ./gradlew androidDepedencies
```